# How to get the list of all the databases in an Azure DocumentDB account?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

In Microsoft Azure DocumentDb, how can I retrieve a list of all databases? Not documents in a particular database, but all the databases for a particular account. Preferable using the standard `DocumentClient` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could something like the following:

```
            using (var documentClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri("<endpoint>"), "<accountkey>"))
            {
                var listDatabasesOperationResult = await documentClient.ReadDatabaseFeedAsync();
                foreach (var item in listDatabasesOperationResult)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
                }
            }
```

Comment: `An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code` -- I wonder why?

Comment: @jawanam could you please provide the full stack trace for this exception. I've never seen a FileNotFoundException in this SDK before.